# I'm getting Invalid Account data error after sending jupiter swap trasaction to solana

Tags: solana-program, flutter

This is what I'm trying on the source code side after getting setup, swap and cleanup transactions from Jupiter v1/swap with 85 feeBps.

```
Future<String?> maybeExecuteTx({
    required String? tx,
    required ValueSetter<SwapException> onError,
  }) async {
    try {
      if (tx == null) return null;

      final message = SignedTx.decode(tx).message;
      final recent = await client.rpcClient.getRecentBlockhash();
      final recompiled = message.compile(recentBlockhash: recent.blockhash);

      final signedTx = SignedTx(
          messageBytes: recompiled.data,
          signatures: [await wallet.sign(recompiled.data)]);

      final transaction = signedTx.encode();
      debugPrint(transaction);

      final signature = await client.rpcClient.sendTransaction(
        transaction,
        preflightCommitment: Commitment.confirmed,
      );
      print(signature);
      await client.waitForSignatureStatus(
        signature,
        status: Commitment.confirmed,
        timeout: const Duration(minutes: 1),
      );

      return signature;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      // onError(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I'm getting below error response from `sendTransaction` method.

`{accounts: null, err: {InstructionError: [2, InvalidAccountData]}, logs: [Program JUP3c2Uh3WA4Ng34tw6kPd2G4C5BB21Xo36Je1s32Ph invoke [1], Program log: Instruction: SetTokenLedger, Program JUP3c2Uh3WA4Ng34tw6kPd2G4C5BB21Xo36Je1s32Ph consumed 3224 of 600000 compute units, Program JUP3c2Uh3WA4Ng34tw6kPd2G4C5BB21Xo36Je1s32Ph success, Program JUP3c2Uh3WA4Ng34tw6kPd2G4C5BB21Xo36Je1s32Ph invoke [1], Program log: Instruction: RaydiumSwapV2, Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [2], Program log: calc_exact len:0, Program consumption: 558871 units remaining, Program consumption: 558763 units remaining, Program log: ray_log: AwAJPQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAFL3TyYBAAAAoq5Hnt6EAQDNzjGoAwAAAJIAAAAAAAAA, Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3], Program log: Instruction: Transfer, Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4645 of 553016 compute units, Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success, Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623V`

Comment: You may need to add more information about the exact transaction you're performing, that way it'll be easier to spot any issues.  This says the third instruction in your transaction has some incorrect account with `InvalidAccountData`, so you can start by looking there.

Comment: @JonC I'm sending Jupiter swap serialized transactions to Solana. There are 3 serialized transactions. And, It's working fine without any feeBps. But, with the feeBps, I'm getting this issue.

Comment: @JonC Now, My swap is successful. I'm not getting any errors. But, I'm applying 85 feeBps which was not collected in my fees account. Could you help me with this?